# How can I handle FCM when my app is not running?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I can receive FCM when app is active or background.

But can't receive when not running.

How can I receive FCM when application state not running?

Answer (score 0):

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.There is a parameter launchOptions  which contains push notification.Store the data and handle it in firstViewController you open.I did it by writing these lines in appDelegate I used swiftyJson and take userPush in singleton class to 1:

```
  guard let pushNotification = launchOptions?
[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]  else { return true }
    print(pushNotification)
    let data = JSON(pushNotification)

    UserDataSingleton.sharedInstance.notificationData = data
    UserDataSingleton.sharedInstance.userPush = 1
```

Now in my splashViewController I did:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    if (UserDataSingleton.sharedInstance.userPush == 1){

        UserDataSingleton.sharedInstance.userPush = 0
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.handlePushNavigation(userInfo: UserDataSingleton.sharedInstance.notificationData!)

    }
    else{

    }

}
```

handlePushNotification is a func i have written for all 3 cases in AppDelegate:

```
//MARK: - HAndle Push Notification Methods

extension AppDelegate{

func handlePush(userInfo : JSON){

    handlePushNavigation(userInfo: userInfo )
}

func handlePushNavigation(userInfo :  JSON){

    let storybard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    switch userInfo["type"].intValue {
    case 1:

        guard let VC = storybard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as? ChatViewController else{return}

        navigateToVc(vc: VC)

    default:break

    }

}

func navigateToVc(vc:UIViewController){

    ez.topMostVC?.presentVC(vc)

}
```

}